# Oidc-client with IdentityServer3 - Angular2, how to logout and login properly

Tags: angular, openid, identityserver3, oidc-client-js

Here's some background, I'm using implicit flow and my token is JWT. To logout, I'm using the method call signoutRedirectCallback.

I want to be able to properly logout. So that I can login as a different user. When doing so, I still have the token from the last user? Is there a way to completely log the user out so that it doesn't have the last user's token? The token still persists for some reason. It seems that the only way to truly logout is when the browser page is closed and the cookie on the identityserver3 gets removed/deleted?

This may also answer my other issue. If the user clicks on a hyperlink on the main grid page and it opens a new tab (ex. details page), if the user logs out on the new tab (details page), the main grid page (old tab) is still logged in? Again, it's the same issue where I'm not completely logged out.

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to properly logout to remove the cookie on the identityserver3? So that it's a clean slate. The token still persists. Thank you.

```
//Here is the code. In my main component I have a menuclick event and this works: 
public MenuClick(event, item)
{
    if (item === "signOut") 
    {
        this.signOut();
    }
}

public signOut() 
{
    this._LoginService.logOut();
}

//Here is the LoginService that calls the oidc-client method:
public logOutCall(): Observable<boolean> 
{
    return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise<boolean> (
        resolve => 
        {
            this._oidcService.logOut();
            resolve(true);
        }
    ));
}
```

The this._oidcService.logOut() calls the actual oidc-client method     signoutRedirectCallback(). This works and it redirects. But the token still persists unless I close the page.

**UPDATE: My testing team has told me that this issue is specifically with Chrome.**

Comment: for some reason you didn't do it properly, it's impossible to give you any suggestion without looking into source code.

Comment: Roman, I basically call the method mentioned above, and then it redirects to the login page. :/

Comment: before doing redirect invalidate a session

Comment: How do you invalidate the session? The redirect happens automagically in the oidc-client library? Thank you.

Comment: do it automagically in the oidc-client library...

Comment: Roman, is there a method call that I need to invoke or an endpoint that I have to call in id3server? I know I can't revoke the token because I'm not using reference tokens. Thank you.

Comment: you can revoke a token if the server returns 401 status

Comment: Roman, to revoke should I make this call? RevokeAsync(string subject, string client); is this the correct call? Thank you.

Comment: Would that call remove the session? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To clear the state managed by the UserManager, call `removeUser`. This should be called for you when you trigger signout, so I'm curious why it's not. Check the logs?

Comment: Brock, I've done both, manually and let the signoutRedirectCallback() call removeUser(). I've checked the logs and it calls removeUser with no errors. The token has not expired and it still persists. This is only in Chrome that the token still persists.

Comment: What type of token? JWT or reference?

Comment: JWT is what we are using.

Comment: On the init of the main page I also call removeUser, to ensure that it's a clean slate. This also doesn't seem to work in Chrome. :/

Comment: JWTs are not revocable. Once they're out there, the only thing that stops them from being used is their expiration.

Comment: Hi Brock, so are your saying that to use removeUser() properly I need to use a reference token instead of a JWT token?

Comment: Depends on your requirements.

Comment: Well, I need to use JWT to pass the claims around. So yes my requirements is that I do need JWT. Would that be an issue?

Comment: You don't need a JWT to call an API. A reference token can achieve the same. JWTs aren't revocable, reference tokens are.

Comment: So using a reference token instead, the removeUser() method will work correctly? And the user will logout properly? Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: a reference token can be revoked, which is what the UserManager will do at signout time.

Comment: I use claims based authorization. Ex. in claims I have a claim called userAuthType = EndUser, I wrote a custom authorization attribute to check the claims. Will I still have access to those claims if I switch to reference token? Thank you.

Comment: So I did switch to reference tokens as you suggested. It works fine with the api's. I login into the client webpage and get a token. This is an end user token. I then go to the admin login website, there I call oidcMgr.removeUser() to clean up any tokens. When I login, I get a new token and it still recognizes me as the end user with the original email? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: @LVDev Hi, were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same scenario but still using JWT tokens. Thanks