# Identity Server 3, logout Js application from all tabs

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect

I am using Identity Server 3 to authenticate a JS Client using the `Implicit` flow and `AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference`

But when i call

```
    manager
        .signoutRedirect()
         .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('error while logging out', error);
            });
```

the user is signed out only from the calling tab, he can still browse the application in the other tabs.

Is it possible to log the user out from all the other tabs ?

I have already checked this question [Oidc-client with IdentityServer3 - Angular2, how to logout and login properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449064/oidc-client-with-identityserver3-angular2-how-to-logout-and-login-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have configured post_logout_redirect_uri in settings object. You can check if the user is logged out of application by checking the session_state value. In the case of JS application, the design of the specification requires to load, in a hidden iframe, the check session endpoint from IdentityServer. The JS application and this iframe can then communicate with the postMessage API.

You can find complete details here on IdentityServer3 documentation https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/jsGettingStarted.html